# Or statement within np.all() function

Tags: python, numpy

Given a 2D array I would like to find rows that are heterogeneous.

I have a 2D numpy-array and applied a condition resulting in another 2D numpy-array of boolean values.
Now I want to find rows that are neither all True or all False.
Is it possible to apply a or statement within np.all?

```
x = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1],
              [2,2,2,1,2,2],
              [3,3,3,3,3,3,]])

y = x > 1

z = ~np.all((y == True) or (y == False), axis=1)
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

A new array[bool] marking heterogeneous rows.
In example: [False, True, False]

Very much welcome: hints to other solutions, or functions.

Comment: Use `|` to replace `or`.

Comment: That returns `[False False False]`.

Comment: `or` is a python operator that only works with scalar values.  `y` is a numpy array with many boolean values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two `np.all`s before or'ing them.

```
x = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1],
              [2,2,2,1,2,2],
              [3,3,3,3,3,3,]])

y = x > 1

z = ~(np.all(y == True, axis=1) | np.all(y == False, axis=1))
```